# Get .app path from a bundle ID?

Tags: macos, applications, big-sur, metadata, mdm

Say I have a bundle ID `com.apple.Safari`, how do I get the path to the app bundle (.app) (`/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Safari.app`) from that?

I need this for my script to automate a task.

Comment: What language is the script in?

Comment: @mmmmmm Python 3 :)

Comment: Then you need [pyobjc](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) and look at the objective C calls which gives you full access to every thing - possibly NSBundle

Comment: @mmmmmm I thought of that library too, but as someone who's not familiar with 
 obj-c / swift or Apple's APIs, I can't figure out how to use the pyobjc library. If you know how to do this in any language, can you post an answer (with code)? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the function you want is LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier but marked as depreciated but no link to what replaces it.

Comment: This way of doing things is programming and off topic here. You would need to ask on SO. I would ask why are you trying to do this there might be ways of solving the wider issue here.

Comment: I agree that this should be asked on SO. I wonder if there's magical command line tool for this, looks like there isn't. @mmmmmm

Comment: Should I close this question? @mmmmmm

Comment: No leave for a bit someone else might have better ideas. But please explain what is the task you are trying to automate as that will help us to have more ideas

Comment: I see this as totally on topic. This is scripting and spotlight and metadata needed to solve this, not SDK level programming IMO. It’s also squarely in a sys admin toolbox for MDM and managing MacOS clients.